# Mongo replset very slow connect from php

Tags: php, mongodb, database-replication, replicaset

I have a problem with connecting to replica set (4 db + 1 arbiter).

Benchmark:

```
<?php
echo "rp: nearest" . PHP_EOL;
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://app1.n.prod,app1.m.prod,app2.m.prod,app1.d.prod/?replicaSet=booklet&readPreference=nearest&readPreferenceTags=dc:nsk");

echo "rp: primary" . PHP_EOL;
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://app1.n.prod,app1.m.prod,app2.m.prod,app1.d.prod/?replicaSet=booklet&readPreference=primary");

echo "rp: secondary" . PHP_EOL;
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://app1.n.prod,app1.m.prod,app2.m.prod,app1.d.prod/?replicaSet=booklet&readPreference=secondary");

echo "localhost, rs" . PHP_EOL;
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/?replicaSet=booklet");

echo "rp: secondary, without rs" . PHP_EOL;
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://app1.n.prod,app1.m.prod,app2.m.prod,app1.d.prod/?readPreference=secondary");

echo "localhost, without rs" . PHP_EOL;
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
```

Results (time in php microtime(true)):

> ```
> rp: nearest
> 1422547256.97
> 1422547258.8778
> rp: primary
> 1422547258.8778
> 1422547259.7998
> rp: secondary
> 1422547259.7999
> 1422547260.7213
> localhost, rs
> 1422547260.7213
> 1422547260.7223
> rp: secondary, without rs
> 1422547260.7223
> 1422547261.4674
> localhost, without rs
> 1422547261.4674
> 1422547261.4683
> ```

Why does connecting to replica set take so long? (1 second per connection)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some additional log info from [MongoLog](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongolog.php), as that reports internal driver activity for establishing connections to replica sets (among many other things). By default, it will emit PHP notices, but you can customize the logging via [MongoLog::setCallback()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongolog.setcallback.php). Having your callback also log a timestamp before each message would let us calculate the delay between each event.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ip instead domain name:

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.10.0.100:27017,10.10.0.101:27017,10.10.0.102:27017/?replicaSet=booklet&readPreference=nearest&readPreferenceTags=dc:nsk");
```